# ¿Cómo posicionar un div al final de un navbar? Con bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap

Necesito posicionar un div al final del navbar, y que al verlo en un dispositivo móvil, este se esconda con el resto del menú

dejo parte del html.

```css
.navbar {
          padding:0rem;
          margin-bottom:2rem;
        }
        .nav-link
        {
            color: White !important;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: 500;
            }
        .nav-item:hover
        {
            background-color: White;
            }
            
        .nav-item > .nav-link:hover
        {
            color: #0071BA !important;
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" style="background-color:#0071BA;">
   <a class="navbar-brand" style="width: 240px;color: White;">Logo</a>
  <div class="navbar-toggler-right">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="color: White; border-color: White;">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column " id="navbar">
    <ul id="nav" class="navbar-nav w-100 px-3" style="margin: 0 !important;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item" ><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item" ><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="subnav" class="navbar-nav w-100 px-3" style="margin: 0 !important;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item" ><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item" ><a class="nav-link" Width="104px" href="#"style="white-space: nowrap;">Item<a> </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="divCierra" class="pull-right navbar-toggler-right" style="background-color: white;height: 80px;vertical-align: middle;border: 1px solid #0071BA;display: flex;align-items: center;float: left;"><div id="div2" style="
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;"><a ID="btnCerrar" class="CerrarCss" >Cerrar sesión<a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Si se dan cuenta, el cerrar sesión queda debajo de los dos menu, pero necesito que ocupe la altura total del navbar y que quede posicionado al final del mismo.

Algo así:

[image: El cerrar sesión a la derecha del todo]

Al revisarlo en un dispositivo móvil, el cerrar sesión queda muy desordenado, pero necesito que se junte con el resto del menú, como un item más

Answer (score 0):

Ya el propio navbar de bootstrap te implementa esto:

[NavBar Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#supported-content)

Solo debes revisar esa documentación y copiar el código que te aprece más adecuado y luego hacer las modificaciones, por ejemplo para lograr lo que quieres tomé el primer ejemplo y solo dejé el primer enlace además del botón a la derecha:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Para que tengas en cuenta bootstrap tiene utilidades que te permiten mostrar u ocultar elementos dependiendo del tamaño del dispositivo, por ejemplo si quieres que el boton solo se vea cuando el tamaño es mediano tendrías que indicar que a partir del tamaño más pequeño `d-none` se debe ocultar pero cuando se llegue al tamaño mediano aparezca `d-mb-block`, quedando:

```
<button class="btn btn-success d-none d-md-block">Boton</button>
```

[Bootstrap display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/)

Comment: El problema es que en el menú tengo dos ul distintos, y el cerrar sesión debe ocupar el alto total del menú, sumando los dos ul.

Comment: @CarlosVidalVidal no importa cuantos <ul> tengas, igual funciona. A qué te refieres con el alto total? Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir más info, como capturas del resultado esperado en móviles.